# Unpermitted parameters: :supplier, :outlet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

now i'm doing a grocery website. I trying to build an order form that can choose select supplier and outlet,so admin can create order by choosing which supplier and outlet, but now it come out error say unpermitted parameters.

Orders Controller

```
 class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  def supplier
   @supplier = Supplier.find(params[:id])
  end

  def outlet
   @outlet = Outlet.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
   @orders = Order.all
  end

  def show
   @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
   @order = Order.new
   @supplier = Supplier.all
   @outlet = Outlet.all
  end

  def create
   @order = Order.new(order_params)
   @supplier_id = Supplier.all
   @outlet_id = Outlet.all
   if @order.save
    flash[:success] = "Succesful create!"
   redirect_to @order
 else
   render 'new'
  end
end

private

def order_params
  params.require(:order).permit(:supplier_id,:grand_total, :order_date,
                                :delivery_date, :delivery_address, :outlet_id)
 end
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "Create Orders") %>
<h1>Create Order</h1>

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <%= form_with(model: @order, local: true) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <%= f.label :supplier %>
  <%= f.select(:supplier, Supplier.all.collect { |l| [ l.name, l.id] }, {class: "form-select"}) %>

  <%= f.label :grand_total %>
  <%= f.number_field :grand_total, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :order_date %>
  <%= f.date_field :order_date, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :delivery_date %>
  <%= f.date_field :delivery_date, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :delivery_address %>
  <%= f.text_field :delivery_address, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :outlet %>
  <%= f.select(:outlet, Outlet.all.collect { |l| [ l.name, l.id] }, {class: "form-select"}) %>


   <%= f.submit "Create order", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
 </div>
</div>
```

Order migration table in schema

```
create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer "supplier_id"
t.integer "grand_total"
t.date "order_date"
t.date "delivery_date"
t.string "delivery_address"
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.integer "outlet_id"
```

end

[parameter in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNp1S.png)

[error in website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZ1TI.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting

```
Unpermitted parameters: :supplier, :outlet
```

is because you're not allowing `:supplier` and `:outlet` params but `:supplier_id` and `:outlet_id` in order_params

**The Fix**

Change this in your view `new.html.erb`

```
<%= f.label :supplier_id %>
<%= f.select(:supplier_id, Supplier.all.collect { |l| [ l.name, l.id] }, {class: "form-select"}) %>

<%= f.label :outlet_id %>
<%= f.select(:outlet_id, Outlet.all.collect { |l| [ l.name, l.id] }, {class: "form-select"}) %>
```

This should fix the issue by allowing the `:supplier_id` and `:outlet_id` params and assigning the object with proper values